# Make methods on added form visible to main form

Tags: c#

I'm working on a class project which simulates aspects of running a business.  On the main form, the user can click a button that moves the simulation forward a month.  On a separate form, the user can do basic things like set sales on certain items.  These sales should end when the user moves forward a month, but I have no way to undo the sales without opening that form.  This raises many issues.  Can someone explain a way I could run a method in the separate form from the main form?

I tried making the method public and going,

```
InventoryForm.checkSales();
```

But it doesn't see checkSales.

Comment: You need to post your code. Describing code isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: "This raises many issues." So us some code and tell us what issues.

Comment: What kind of forms? Web Forms?

Comment: You cannot simply write `InventoryForm`, that's a *type*, not an *instance* of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Implying this is windows forms*
*Implying this is the way your program is structured*

The classes should be visible to each other as long as they are in the same [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If you have two forms declared like so :

- Form1
- Form2

And you want to access from `Form2` a method declared in `Form1`, you either have to create a new instance of `Form1` or make sure that your method is static (usually bad practice but it happens e.g [Math Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.math.aspx)) so that you can access it with the class name only. You could also create an event and subscribe to it in another form.

```
// Option 1 : (New Instance)

public class Form2()
{
   Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
     // Create new instance of Form1
     Form1 form1 = new Form1();
     form1.MyForm1Method();
   }
} 

//Option 2 : (Static)
 public class Form2()
{
   Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
     // Method is static in Form1 (The class would be static too)
     Form1.MyForm1Method();
   }
} 

// Option 3 (Event Subscribtion)

//Form1:

private void StartForm2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.SomethingHappened += Form2_SomethingHappened;
    form2.Show();
}

private Form2_SomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = (Form2)sender;
    string data = form2.Data;
    // create node
    AddNode(node);
}


//Form2:

public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

public string Data
{
   get { return textBoxData.Text; }
}

private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SomethingHappened != null)
        SomethingHappened(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Declare the checkSales method as static

```
  Public static void checkSales() ...
```